# Include foreign keys in MySQL data dictionary

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, data-dictionary

I am producing a data dictionary for a particular schema in MySQL. So far, I have the table_name, columm_name, column_type (as below in the SELECT statement). How do I include what the foreign key constraints are as well, in the same data dictionary? I would like to put the foreign key info. into this format:

```
CONCAT(table_name, '.', column_name, ' -> ', referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name)
```

---

```
select  
t.table_name,
c.column_name,
c.column_type

from
information_schema.tables as t
    inner join
information_schema.columns as c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
    and t.table_schema = c.table_schema
where
t.table_type in ('base table' , 'view')
    and t.table_schema like 'mySchema'
order by t.table_schema , t.table_name , c.ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of table constraints can be found in *table_constraints* table. From this table you can fetch all foreign keys by getting all rows with:

```
constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'
```

This will give you just a list of foreign keys, if you need more details (e.g. which table and column they point to) have a look at key_column_usage table:

```
mysql> describe key_column_usage;
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG            | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA             | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| CONSTRAINT_NAME               | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_CATALOG                 | varchar(512) | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_SCHEMA                  | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| TABLE_NAME                    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| COLUMN_NAME                   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       |
| ORDINAL_POSITION              | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT | bigint(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA       | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME         | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME        | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to do this, BUT how do I join the specific column_type info. to this?  `select
table_name, column_name, constraint_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
where
table_schema like 'mySchemaName';`

Comment: In order to join data from both tables you can use constraint_name, if they're unique, or constraint_name+table_name if not.

Comment: Hi, I keep getting an error that `constraint_name` is an unknown column in 'field list', and alternatively in 'on clause'. Any pointers on how to properly join?

Comment: Could you paste your query here? I'll try to debug locally

Comment: Thanks for helping, ended up sorting out the joins properly, so all is good.